# How to call a C function from Swift whose name coincides with a structure?

Tags: c, swift, interop, swift4.2

In C, there are separate namespaces for functions and for structures. Module Darwin exports both `struct flock` and `func flock`. If I try to call the function, the compiler resolves the name to the structure initialiser:

```
let result: Int32 = Darwin.flock(fd, LOCK_EX)
                           ^^^^^
                           Cannot invoke initializer
                           for type 'flock' with an argument list
                           of type '(Int32, Int32)'
```

If I try to resolve the name manually through a named import, I still get an error:

```
import func Darwin.flock
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
            Ambiguous name 'flock' in module 'Darwin'
```

Also no luck with a reference to a function:

```
let functionNotStruct: (Int32, Int32) -> Int32 = Darwin.flock
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       Cannot convert value of type 'flock.Type'
                       to specified type '(Int32, Int32) -> Int32'
```

Is there any way to tell the compiler I want the function and not the initialiser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot explain why it makes a difference, but *omitting* the module name makes it compile:

```
// Call `flock()`:
let result = flock(fd, LOCK_EX)

// Use `struct flock`:
var fl = flock()
fl.l_start = 0
```